# Get content of a string variable using getattr

Tags: python, string, getattr

I would like to know how to retrieve the content of a string variable so that I can use its value as an argument name in a function.
Here the code:

```
import pandas
import jinja2

oDateList = ['2017-03-22','2017-03-23','2017-03-24']
oData = pandas.DataFrame()
oData['Date'] = oDateList
MyTemplate = 'Today is {{ Date }}'
oTemplate = jinja2.Template(MyTemplate)

for oRow in oData.index:
    for oColumn in oData.columns:
        MyTemplateUpdated = oTemplate.render(Date=oData.loc[oRow, oColumn])
        print(MyTemplateUpdated)
```

It works well and returns:

```
Today is 2017-03-22
Today is 2017-03-23
Today is 2017-03-24
```

I would like to dynamically retrieve the argument name `Date=` from the dataframe column name `oColumn` (which is 'Date'). I thought about using `getattr(oColumn, 'something')` but did not figure out how to do so.

I have also tried `str(oColumn)` and it returns the error: `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `str(oColumn)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to dynamically set the argument name being sent to a function, you'll need to use kwargs.

```
render(**{argument_name: argument_value}
```

So in your case, assuming that oColumn contains the string you wish to be the argument, it would look something like this;

```
render(**{oColumn: oData.loc[oRow, oColumn]})
```

Let me know if I have misunderstood your intent.

Comment: Thank you but could you please describe how you would integrate that in the script above? I am not very familiar with kwargs.

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland - does this elaboration help?

Comment: Definitelly, you understood well and it works like a charm! Thank you!